# In Angular 14 and PrimeNG, how do I get the state of a checkbox in the click handler?

Tags: checkbox, onclick, primeng, angular14

I'm using PrimeNG and Angular 14.  I have a checkbox in my p-table

```
<p-tableCheckbox (click)="onSelectAll($event)"></p-tableCheckbox>
```

I would like to know if the state of the box is checked or unchecked.  So I tried

onSelectAll(event: any) {
if (event.checked) {
this.selectedCustomers = this.customers.slice(); // select all
} else {
this.selectedCustomers = []; // unselect all
}
}

but "event.checked" is repeatedly undefined.  I also tried "event.target.checked" but to no avail.  How do I tell if my checkbox is checked or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should to use these three events on `p-table` tag itself not on `p-tableCheckbox`

```
  <p-table 
    
    (onRowSelect)="pass your function here"
    (onRowUnselect)="pass your function here"
    (onHeaderCheckboxToggle)="pass your function here"
```

> don't forget to add selection array for your rows `[(selection)]="selectionRowsArr"`

- onRowSelect : will give you the selected row inside `event.data`
- onRowUnselect : will give you the unselected row inside `event.data`
- onHeaderCheckboxToggle : will give you if this check box checked or
  not inside `event.checked`

you can check this link:
[check table event and type of selection tabels](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tableselection-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)